# Applications of Random Walks for undergraduate students

Tags: probability, education, random-walk

Students are asking for applications of discrete random walks in "real life" problems. By real life they mean financial applications and industry. We have two more weeks on this subjects and I'm willing to give up my theorectical lessons to keep their interest up. Can you suggest some reference about this? Applications using continuous random walks are possible as well, as I already prepared the lessons on embedding.

Comment: You could talk about the binomial pricing model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model

Comment: If you already know about Black-Scholes and similar pricing models (which usually are formulated in the context of stochastic differential equations), I think you could probably adapt most of its content to the discrete space (maybe discrete time as well) setting.

Comment: An one dimensional random walk can be viewed as a Markov Chain. You could mention applications of markov chains (predictive models) as well as probabilistic automata (computation machine which can be viewed as random transition between states of the machine)

Comment: Thank you all. I prepared a lecture about the PageRank (as introduction to the upcoming Markov Chains) and the binomial pricing model. They liked it a lot. Much more than the (even more) theoretical lessons :( hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting paper dealing with a random walk is M. Orkin and R. Kakigi, "What is the worth of free casino credit," *The American Mathematical Monthly* Vol. 102 (1995). This application is also discussed in the book *Understanding Probability* by Henk Tijms. Chapter 5 of this book gives several other  applications of random walks that are of interest in finance.